# jQuery: Autocomplete, don't close at button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery UI autocomplete list and want it to open and close at click in the input field or on an icon. 
The autocomplete closes automatically when I click anywhere else on the page. Which is good. But: I don't want this closing automatism to trigger when I click on my icon. At the moment, when the list is open and I click on the icon, the list first closes (due to the automatism) and then immediately re-opens.

Can I somehow prevent the automatic closing only for clicks on the icon?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>...</title>

      <!-- Bootstrap -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

      <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div class=container>
         <span id="regionGlyph" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right "></span>
         <input id="regionIn" type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>

      <script>
         $(document).ready( function() {
            var availableTags = 
               ["Aach (BW)",
               "Aachen (NW)",
               "Aalen (BW)",
               "Abenberg (BY)",
               "Abensberg (BY)",
               "Achern (BW)",
               "Achim (NI)",
               "Adelsheim (BW)",
               "Adenau (RP)",
               "Adorf/Vogtl. (SN)",
               "Ahaus (NW)",
               "Ahlen (NW)",
               "Ahrensburg (SH)",
               "Aichach (BY)",
               "Aichtal (BW)",
               "Aken (Elbe) (ST)",
               "Albstadt (BW)",
               "Alfeld (Leine) (NI)",
               "Allendorf (Lumda) (HE)",
               "Allstedt (ST)",
               "Alpirsbach (BW)",
               "Arnsberg (NW)"];

            var closed=true;
            $( "#regionIn" ).autocomplete({
               source: availableTags,
               minLength: 0,
               close: function(){
                         closed=true;
                      },
               search: function(){
                          closed=false;
                       }
            })
            .click(function() {
               if (closed){
                  $(this).autocomplete('search');
               } else {
                  $(this).autocomplete('close');
               };
             });

             $("#regionGlyph").click(function(){
                $("#regionIn").trigger("click");
             });
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6e2mtr69/).

Comment: You mean something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6e2mtr69/2/)?

Comment: Looks correct, but seems to have exactly the same issue as my code. Plus, it's not even opening the autocomplete in my browser (????).

Comment: Which issue? This fiddle works for me. If you click on the icon and autocomplete is closed the window opens. if the window is open and you click on the icon nothing happens.

Comment: Yeah exacty, but I actually wanted the autocomplete to close at click on the icon. At the moment it closes and re-opens at one click. That's the issue.

Comment: @PeMa checkout my answer

Comment: @prabhjot Hehe, nice hack.

Comment: @PeMa ask for help whenever needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your fiddle . you can check out here. its working now. just used some little tricks.
https://jsfiddle.net/6e2mtr69/4/

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var availableTags = ["Aach (BW)",
     "Aachen (NW)",
     "Aalen (BW)",
     "Abenberg (BY)",
     "Abensberg (BY)",
     "Achern (BW)",
     "Achim (NI)",
     "Adelsheim (BW)",
     "Adenau (RP)",
     "Adorf/Vogtl. (SN)",
     "Ahaus (NW)",
     "Ahlen (NW)",
     "Ahrensburg (SH)",
     "Aichach (BY)",
     "Aichtal (BW)",
     "Aken (Elbe) (ST)",
     "Albstadt (BW)",
     "Alfeld (Leine) (NI)",
     "Allendorf (Lumda) (HE)",
     "Allstedt (ST)",
     "Alpirsbach (BW)",
     "Arnsberg (NW)"
   ];

   var closed = true;
   $("#regionIn").autocomplete({
       source: availableTags,
       minLength: 0,
       close: function() {
         closed = true;
                 $('#regionGlyph').show();
                 $('#regionGlyph_1').hide();

       },
       search: function() {
         closed = false;
                 $('#regionGlyph_1').show();
                 $('#regionGlyph').hide();
                 }
     })
     .click(function() {
       if (closed) {
         $(this).autocomplete('search');
       } else {
         $(this).autocomplete('close');
       };
     });

   $("#regionGlyph").click(function() {
     $('#regionIn').autocomplete('search');
   });
 });
```

here is the html  just little changes

```
<div class=container>
  <span id="regionGlyph" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right "></span>
    <span id="regionGlyph_1" style="display:none" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right "></span><br>
  <input id="regionIn" type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```